# How to plot coarse-grained average of a set of data points?

Tags: python

I have a set of discrete 2-dimensional data points.  Each of these points has a measured value associated with it.  I would like to get a scatter plot with points colored by their measured values.  But the data points are so dense that points with different colors would overlap with each other, that may not be good for visualization. So I am thinking if I could associate the color for each point based on the coarse-grained average of measured values of some points near it.  Does anyone know how to implement this in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it done by using `sklearn.neighbors.RadiusNeighborsClassifier()`, the idea is the take the average of the values of the neighbors within a specific radius.  Suppose the coordinates of the data points are in the list `temp_coors`, the values associated with these points are `coloring`, then `coloring` could be coarse-grained in the following way:

```
r_neigh = RadiusNeighborsRegressor(radius=smoothing_radius, weights='uniform')
r_neigh.fit(temp_coors, coloring)
coloring = r_neigh.predict(temp_coors)
```